# What does this error mean? cannot subscript value type

Tags: ios, swift

getting error: cannot subscript value type [String:Double]with an index typ Int

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {//1
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) //2
        cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

My `MenuItems` looks as follows:

```
class MenuItems:NSObject{

    var sections:[String] = []
    var items:[[String:Double]] = []

    func addSection(section: String, item:[String:Double]){
        sections = sections + [section]
        items = items + [item]
    }
}

class AnnMenuItems: MenuItems {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        addSection("Threading", item: ["Eye Brows":100,"Upper Lip":100,"Forehead":100,"Chin":100,"Sides":100,"Face Waxing/Face Threading":100])
        addSection("Hair", item: ["Rebonding":100,"Hair Dye":100,"Head Massage":100,"Streaking":100,"Hair Cut":100,"Straight Cut":100,"Children Cut":100,"Step Cut":100,"Layer Cut":100])
        addSection("Waxing", item: ["Full Arms":100,"3/4 Arms":100,"Under Arms":100,"Full Legs":100, "3/4 Legs":100,"Half Legs":100])
        addSection("Hair Treatments", item: ["Hair Spa":100,"Dandruff":100,"Hair Fall Treatment":100,"Galvanic Treatment":100, "Hair Wash":100,"Colour/Henna/Oil":100])
        addSection("Facial", item: ["Clean Up Normal":100,"Black Heads":100,"Clean Up Special":100,"Herbal Facial":100, "Fruit Facial":100])
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `menuItems.items` is dictionary..and you can not take index of dictionary

Comment: yea. so how do i do it?

Comment: @iosmadness There are a lot of ways to do it, but all of those require to change `menuItems` type.

Comment: What should the `text` be? `Threading` or `Eye Brows` or `100`?

Comment: `Threading` is the heading item; subsection of `Eye Brows` which is priced at `100`. and i want to put this on a static table cell. the `text` should be `Eye Brows : 100`

Comment: okay, will post a solution shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `menuItems.items` are `Dictionary`s of type `[String:Double]`, meaning its keys are `String`s while its values are `Double`s.

You are now trying to get the value for the key `indexPath.row`, which is an `Int`. But the key is as we just said `String`.

You cannot and should not access a dictionary by index since is an unordered data container.

*Edit*:

If you are using sections and are trying to store *all* item data in one property, then that property should be of type `[[TheObjectYouStore]]`. The outer array is the section, the inner array is the row. You currently only have `[TheObjectYouStore]` while the property you store actually is a dictionary.

What you therefore should do is create a new Class/struct named `Item` which has a `description` and a `number`, for example `description="Eye Brows", number=100`. You then change your signature of the method `addSection` and the type of `items` accordingly:

```
struct Item {
    var description : String
    var number : Int
}
var items:[[Item]] = []

func addSection(section: String, item:[Item]){
    sections = sections + [section]
    items = items + [item]
}
```

Comment: @iosmadness I provided a solution, take a look

Comment: thank you @luke2302. I am a noob at swift. how should the new class/struct look like

Comment: @iosmadness I added the struct for you

Comment: on final thing how do i adjust the addsection values. they're giving me an error. contextual type [Item] cannot be used with dictionary literal

Comment: @iosmadness to createa a new Item use `Item(description: "Eye brows", number: 100)` etc.